# How do I divide a polygon into tributary areas?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a polygon and lines representing load bearing beams traversing that polygon. How should I divide the polygon into the tributary areas each beam is responsible for?

Edit: The tributary area is the area which transfers its loads to a particular supporting element. The tributary area usually represents half the area all around the supporting element to the next supporting element. For example, if two columns are 8 feet apart, 4 feet transfer its load to one column and the other 4 feet to the other column.

Edit 2: In the image below, you can see the beams supported by columns. Also, you can see red lines marking the tributary areas, which are midway between the edges and beams.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific, perhaps add an image of your problem?

Comment: I've added a definition for "Tributary Area"

Comment: I assume that the upper edges in the image are supporting, so that some areas (viz. the one in the upper left corner) does not seem to contain any column. Am I right?

Comment: I've added an image depicing tributary areas.

Comment: @CoffeeonMars, I think you are correct. In my scenario, the edges are always supporting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are seeking the [medial axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) or the [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), but your description is too terse
(and therefore ambiguous) to be certain.  You need to explain how the "tributary areas" that
each beam (chord?) "is responsible for" are defined.  If by distance to closest beam, then
you want the Voronoi diagram of the beams confined to the polygon.

Comment: I've added an image and a definition to help explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard to understand your question with no illustrations. In general, you might want to check out a polygon sweep algorithm if you want to subdivide a polygon. Try these links:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall99/cs426/lectures/scan/sld028.htm

http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Partition_2/Chapter_main.html

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to subdivide a polygon. It is already divided into regions by the beams. (I would put up an illustration if I knew how.)

Comment: To add an image, use the image button above the edit field, or press CTRL+G.